# Hadoop FileSystem.getConf throws java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am using Hadoop-1.0.4 and performing some file system related operation using java api.Its working properly but sometimes I get following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:925)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<init>(UserGroupInformation.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:452)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1494)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1395)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
```

I tried to google for the error and found the similar question in this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201504.mbox/%3C0B87C97B6D8E0B43BAF497C2B90FA0F3E29974B705@AUSX7MCPC101.AMER.DELL.COM%3E).But no answer :( .Any help will be greatly appriciated

Following is the code snippet where I get this error:

```
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310");
        FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar error in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25780195/5009363). Check the version of the rest of the components and look for hadoop core 1.0.4 info to know which the right libraries you can match are with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to create remote user but it didn't worked :(. Also if this issue is related to libraries then it should not work at all.But this issue is reproduce only when application is ran multiple times

Comment: Using any IDE like eclipse or netbeans? If so, add an exception breakpoint so that your program stops before a NoSuchElementException is gonna happen and you can check your call stack and figure out what is happening.